# Ignoring mimetype in git

Tags: git, mime-types, gitignore

Is it possible not only to ignore on *filename* only, but on the *mimetype* as well? Since the mimetype sometimes depends on the "magical numbers" in a file, this can generate an additional disambiguation between different kind of files.

Comment: What filtering are you referring to? Also, it seems the title of the question contradicts the first sentence.

Comment: @MagnusBack: Fixed, I hope?

Comment: @CommuSoft A question mark at the end of a question is helpful ;)

Comment: You could do some [`pre-commit` hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) magic, though that would only affect commits and not e.g. `git status` if you already accidentally comitted a to-be-ignored file...